# Robotframework-SudsLibrbary : No keyword with the name "Create Soap Client " found

Tags: robotframework, suds

I am trying to use 
Robotframework-Sudslibrary for my soap requests. After a lot of issues was able to successfully install Robotframework-sudslibrary  & suds-jurko . I am using Python36 . When I try to run this following code ,

```
*** Settings ***
Library           XML
Library           Collections
Library           SudsLibrary

*** Test Cases ***

Secured WSDL

create soap client         https://testorg.com/test.asmx?wsdl
```

I am getting the following error ,

> [ ERROR ] Error in file 'robot-scripts\Tests\soaptest.robot':
>   Initializing test library 'SudsLibrary' with no arguments failed:
>   NameError: name 'urllib2' is not defined
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\robotframework_sudslibrary-0.9.dev0-py3.6.egg\SudsLibrary__init__.py", line 184, in **init**
>       raise e
>     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\robotframework_sudslibrary-0.9.dev0-py3.6.egg\SudsLibrary__init__.py", line 179, in **init**
>       part = urllib2.**version**.split('.', 1)
>
> No keyword with name 'create soap client' found.

Any help/Suggestions will be really helpful.

Comment: I am not sure why the whole code is formatted properly. I apologize.

Comment: Still struggling.Any inputs ??